# Android uncaught typeError when load a JS file

Tags: javascript, android

I'm making an app with WebView and javascript on the page not open, and the problem seems to be in my JS file because the logcat showed the following line:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Can not set property 'id' of undefined at file :/ / / android_asset / js / colorpicker.js: 4
```

the interesting thing is that this error only happens when I run it with android 4.1.2 and earlier 
when running with 4.4.2 this works, 
how can I do so that android 4.1.2 accepted this js file as 4.4.2 does?

**CODE:**

```
        (function(g,p,n){function v(a){if(g.event&&g.event.contentOverflow!==n)return{x:g.event.offsetX,y:g.event.offsetY};
    if(a.offsetX!==n&&a.offsetY!==n)return{x:a.offsetX,y:a.offsetY};
    var b=a.target.parentNode.parentNode;
    return{x:a.layerX-b.offsetLeft,y:a.layerY-b.offsetTop}}function e(a,b,c){a=p.createElementNS(z,a);
    for(var d in b)a.setAttribute(d,b[d]);
    "[object Array]"!=Object.prototype.toString.call(c)&&(c=[c]);
    b=0;
    for(d=c[0]&&c.length||0;
    b<d;
    b++)a.appendChild(c[b]);
    return a}function h(a){var b,c,d,j,e=a.h%360/60;
    j=a.v*a.s;
    d=j*(1-Math.abs(e%2-1));
    b=c=a=a.v-j;
    e=~~e;
    b+=[j,d,0,0,d,j][e];
    c+=[d,j,j,d,0,0][e];
    a+=[0,0,d,j,j,d][e];
    d=Math.floor(255*b);
    c=Math.floor(255*c);
    a=Math.floor(255*a);
    return{r:d,g:c,b:a,hex:"#"+(16777216|a|c<<8|d<<16).toString(16).slice(1)}}function q(a){var b=a.r,c=a.g,d=a.b;

        if
    (1<a.r||1<a.g||1<a.b)b/=255,c/=255,d/=255;
    var e;
    a=Math.max(b,c,d);
    e=a-Math.min(b,c,d);
    b=60*((0==e?0:a==b?(c-d)/e+(c<d?6:0):a==c?(d-b)/e+2:(b-c)/e+4)%6);

    return{h:b,s:0==e?0:e/a,v:a}}function w(a,b,c){return function(d){d=d||g.event;
    d=v(d);
    a.h=360*(d.y/b.offsetHeight)+s;
    a.s=a.v=1;
    var e=h({h:a.h,s:1,v:1});
    c.style.backgroundColor=e.hex;
    a.callback&&a.callback(e.hex,{h:a.h-s,s:a.s,v:a.v},{r:e.r,g:e.g,b:e.b},n,d)}}function x(a,b){return function(c){c=c||g.event;
    c=v(c);
    var d=b.offsetHeight;
    a.s=c.x/b.offsetWidth;
    a.v=(d-c.y)/d;
    d=h(a);
    a.callback&&a.callback(d.hex,{h:a.h-s,s:a.s,v:a.v},{r:d.r,g:d.g,b:d.b},c)}}function f(a,b,c){if(!(this instanceof f))return new f(a,b,c);
    this.h=0;
    this.v=this.s=1;
    if(c)this.callback=c,this.pickerElement=b,this.slideElement=a;
    else{a.innerHTML=A;
    this.slideElement=a.getElementsByClassName("slide")[0];
    this.pickerElement=a.getElementsByClassName("picker")[0];
    var d=a.getElementsByClassName("slide-indicator")[0],e=a.getElementsByClassName("picker-indicator")[0];
    f.fixIndicators(d,e);
    this.callback=function(a,c,g,h,k){f.positionIndicators(d,e,k,h);

    b(a,c,g)}}"SVG"==t?(a=k.getElementsByTagName("linearGradient")                          [0],c=k.getElementsByTagName("rect")[0],a.id="gradient-hsv- "+r,c.setAttribute("fill","url(#"+a.id+")"),a=l.getElementsByTagName("linearGradient"),c=l.getElement   sByTagName("rect"),a[0].id="gradient-black-"+r,a[1].id="gradient-white-         "+r,c[0].setAttribute("fill","url(#"+a[1].id+")"),c[1].setAttribute("fill","url(#"+a[0].id+")"),this.   slideElement.appendChild(k.cloneNode(!0)),this.pickerElement.appendChild(l.cloneNode(!0)),r++):     (this.slideElement.innerHTML=k,this.pickerElement.innerHTML=l);

    m(this.slideElement,"click",w(this,this.slideElement,this.pickerElement));
    m(this.pickerElement,"click",x(this,this.pickerElement));
    y(this,this.slideElement,w(this,this.slideElement,this.pickerElement));
    y(this,this.pickerElement,x(this,this.pickerElement))}function m(a,b,c){a.attachEvent?a.attachEvent("on"+b,c):a.addEventListener&&a.addEventListener(b,c,!1)}function y(a,b,c){var d=!1;
    m(b,"mousedown",function(){d=!0});
    m(b,"mouseup",function(){d=!1});
    m(b,"mouseout",function(){d=!1});
    m(b,"mousemove",function(a){d&&c(a)})}function u(a,b,c,d){a.h=b.h%360;
    a.s=b.s;
    a.v=b.v;
    b=h(a);
    var e={y:a.h*a.slideElement.offsetHeight/360,x:0},f=a.pickerElement.offsetHeight,f={x:a.s*a.pickerElement.offsetWidth,y:f-a.v*f};
    a.pickerElement.style.backgroundColor=h({h:a.h,s:1,v:1}).hex;
    a.callback&&a.callback(d||b.hex,{h:a.h,s:a.s,v:a.v},c||{r:b.r,g:b.g,b:b.b},f,e);
    return a}var t=g.SVGAngle||p.implementation.hasFeature?"SVG":"VML",l,k,s=15,z="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",A='<div class="picker-wrapper"><div class="picker"></div><div class="picker-indicator"></div></div><div class="slide-wrapper"><div class="slide"></div><div class="slide-indicator"></div></div>';

    "SVG"==t?(k=e("svg",{version:"1.1",width:"100%",height:"100%"},[e("defs",{},e("linearGradient",{id:"gradient-hsv",x1:"0%",y1:"100%",x2:"0%",y2:"0%"},[e("stop",{offset:"0%","stop-color":"#FF0000","stop-opacity":"1"}),e("stop",{offset:"13%","stop-color":"#FF00FF","stop-opacity":"1"}),e("stop",{offset:"25%","stop-color":"#8000FF","stop-opacity":"1"}),e("stop",{offset:"38%","stop-color":"#0040FF","stop-opacity":"1"}),e("stop",{offset:"50%","stop-color":"#00FFFF","stop-opacity":"1"}),e("stop",{offset:"63%","stop-color":"#00FF40","stop-opacity":"1"}),e("stop",{offset:"75%","stop-color":"#0BED00","stop-opacity":"1"}),e("stop",{offset:"88%","stop-color":"#FFFF00","stop-opacity":"1"}),e("stop",{offset:"100%","stop-color":"#FF0000","stop-opacity":"1"})])),e("rect",{x:"0",y:"0",width:"100%",height:"100%",fill:"url(#gradient-hsv)"})]),l=e("svg",{xmlns:"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",version:"1.1",width:"100%",height:"100%"},[e("defs",{},[e("linearGradient",{id:"gradient-black",x1:"0%",
y1:"100%",x2:"0%",y2:"0%"},[e("stop",{offset:"0%","stop-color":"#000000","stop-opacity":"1"}),e("stop",{offset:"100%","stop-color":"#CC9A81","stop-opacity":"0"})]),e("linearGradient",{id:"gradient-white",x1:"0%",y1:"100%",x2:"100%",y2:"100%"},[e("stop",{offset:"0%","stop-color":"#FFFFFF","stop-opacity":"1"}),e("stop",{offset:"100%","stop-color":"#CC9A81","stop-opacity":"0"})])]),e("rect",{x:"0",y:"0",width:"100%",height:"100%",fill:"url(#gradient-white)"}),e("rect",{x:"0",y:"0",width:"100%",height:"100%",
fill:"url(#gradient-black)"})])):"VML"==t&&(k='<DIV style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%"><v:rect style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%" stroked="f" filled="t"><v:fill type="gradient" method="none" angle="0" color="red" color2="red" colors="8519f fuchsia;.25 #8000ff;24903f #0040ff;.5 aqua;41287f #00ff40;.75 #0bed00;57671f yellow"></v:fill></v:rect></DIV>',l='<DIV style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%"><v:rect style="position: absolute; left: -1px; top: -1px; width: 101%; height: 101%" stroked="f" filled="t"><v:fill type="gradient" method="none" angle="270" color="#FFFFFF" opacity="100%" color2="#CC9A81" o:opacity2="0%"></v:fill></v:rect><v:rect style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 101%" stroked="f" filled="t"><v:fill type="gradient" method="none" angle="0" color="#000000" opacity="100%" color2="#CC9A81" o:opacity2="0%"></v:fill></v:rect></DIV>',
    p.namespaces.v||p.namespaces.add("v","urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml","#default#VML"));

    var r=0;
    f.hsv2rgb=function(a){a=h(a);
    delete a.hex;
    return a};
    f.hsv2hex=function(a){return h(a).hex};
    f.rgb2hsv=q;
    f.rgb2hex=function(a){return h(q(a)).hex};
    f.hex2hsv=function(a){return q(f.hex2rgb(a))};
    f.hex2rgb=function(a){return{r:parseInt(a.substr(1,2),16),g:parseInt(a.substr(3,2),16),b:parseInt(a.substr(5,2),16)}};
    f.prototype.setHsv=function(a){return u(this,a)};
    f.prototype.setRgb=function(a){return u(this,q(a),a)};
    f.prototype.setHex=function(a){return u(this,f.hex2hsv(a),n,a)};
    f.positionIndicators=function(a,b,c,d){c&&(b.style.left="auto",b.style.right="0px",b.style.top="0px",a.style.top=c.y-a.offsetHeight/2+"px");
          d&&(b.style.top=d.y-b.offsetHeight/2+"px",b.style.left=d.x-b.offsetWidth/2+"px")};
       f.fixIndicators=function(a,b){b.style.pointerEvents="none";
      a.style.pointerEvents="none"};
      g.ColorPicker=f})(window,window.document);
```

Comment: I think you should format your code a little bit

Comment: i did try .. can u help me do that ?

Comment: Okay, I'll help you: Start by learning to [always use braces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020228) for control structures (like **for** or **if-then-else**), even in languages where they're optional for single statements. I've edited literally hundreds of posts to improve code formatting, but I refuse to even touch one that omits the braces.

Comment: ok, I really appreciate your help, thanks! i'm new in javascript and i'll keep learning!

Comment: For example you can make some dynamic apps with css3 and html like : http://codepen.io/iliadraznin/pen/JcqbE , but is not that conventional. Therefor javascript and sometime flash are the most frequent players in the browser.

Comment: some kind soul would help me organize this code to the android 4.1.2 can read this js file ??? I'm new to javascript, i just need finish the app for my father business. I appreciate any help!

Comment: How did you resolve the issue? Could you please post your answer?