# java nested if statement else not working

Tags: java

the else part of the statement is not executing when none of the other statements are true.

```
if (personPlay.equals(computerPlay))  
        System.out.println("It's a tie!");
    else if (personPlay.equals("R"))
        if (computerPlay.equals("S")) 
        System.out.println("Rock crushes scissors.  You win!!");
    else if (personPlay.equals("P"))
        if (computerPlay.equals("R")) 
        System.out.println("Paper raps around rock. You win!");
    else if (personPlay.equals("S"))
        if (computerPlay.equals("P"))
        System.out.println("Scissors cut paper. You win!");
    else 
        System.out.println("you lose");
```

Comment: Use brackets `{ }` and you will discover where the error lies.

Comment: It's because the second else if right now is checking the nested if of the first else if. Same with third else if for second one, etc. You need to add some brackets

Comment: Look at [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020228/is-it-ok-if-i-omit-curly-braces-in-java).

Answer (score 3):

Use brackets :

```
if (personPlay.equals(computerPlay)) {
    System.out.println("It's a tie!");
} else if (personPlay.equals("R")) {
    if (computerPlay.equals("S")) 
      System.out.println("Rock crushes scissors.  You win!!");
} else if (personPlay.equals("P")) {
    if (computerPlay.equals("R")) 
        System.out.println("Paper wraps around rock. You win!");
} else if (personPlay.equals("S")) {
    if (computerPlay.equals("P"))
        System.out.println("Scissors cut paper. You win!");
} else {
    System.out.println("you lose");
}
```

As mentioned in comments, this code would still not work, since the logic is flawed. You should either have an else clause in each internal `if`, in which you should print "you lose" :

```
if (personPlay.equals(computerPlay)) {
    System.out.println("It's a tie!");
} else if (personPlay.equals("R")) {
    if (computerPlay.equals("S")) 
        System.out.println("Rock crushes scissors.  You win!!");
    else 
        System.out.println("you lose");
} else if (personPlay.equals("P")) {
    if (computerPlay.equals("R")) 
        System.out.println("Paper wraps around rock. You win!");
    else 
        System.out.println("you lose");
} else if (personPlay.equals("S")) {
    if (computerPlay.equals("P"))
        System.out.println("Scissors cut paper. You win!");
    else 
        System.out.println("you lose");
} else {
    System.out.println("invalid input");
}
```

Or you could eliminate the inner `if`s and use `&&` instead :

```
if (personPlay.equals(computerPlay)) {
    System.out.println("It's a tie!");
} else if (personPlay.equals("R") && computerPlay.equals("S")) {
      System.out.println("Rock crushes scissors.  You win!!");
} else if (personPlay.equals("P") && computerPlay.equals("R")) { 
        System.out.println("Paper wraps around rock. You win!");
} else if (personPlay.equals("S") && computerPlay.equals("P")) {
        System.out.println("Scissors cut paper. You win!");
} else {
    System.out.println("you lose");
}
```

Comment: real programmers do not need brackets to hold their teeth ;)

Comment: You might want to fix his logic too :) The user never gets "you lose" unless using bad input.

Comment: Use brackets everytime, even for the nested ifs.

Comment: This is a great exercise to learn about `&&` operator.

Comment: @user1071777 That's a good point.