# Slot machine program

Tags: java, eclipse, oop, syntax

Hey I am trying to program a game that simulates a slot machine and implements an interface Game with three methods

```
public String getPrize();
public String equipmentNeeded();
public String rules();
```

I thought I had successfully created the game but it isnt compiling and neither eclipse or my current knowledge on java syntax is showing the problem. This is the code so far:

```
public class SlotMachine implements Game {
    private double Balance=15;
    private boolean enoughMoney, won=false;



public String getPrize() {
    String s=""+Balance;
    return s;
}


public String equipmentNeeded() {
    if(Balance<5){
        enoughMoney=false;
        return "You need more money.";
    }
    else
        enoughMoney=true;
        return "Good luck... the game definetely isn't rigged";
}


public String rules() {
    return "The game costs five cents to play. If you win, you get ten cents. To start the game you must pull the lever that spins the wheels. If 3 out of the 5 wheels have cherries and the remaining wheels aren't lemons then you win!";

}
public boolean pullLever(){
    if(enoughMoney)
        return true;
    else{
        System.out.println("You have "+Balance+". You need at least five to play");
        return false;
    }
}
public void playGame(){
    String choices[]={"cherries", "oranges", "lemons", "wild card", "bananas"};
    String guess[]=new String[5];
    Balance=Balance-5;
    if(pullLever()){
        for(int i=0; i<choices.length; i++){
            guess[i]=choices[(int)(Math.random()*6)];
        }
        for(int x=0; x<guess.length-2; x++){
            if(guess[x].equals("cherries")==false){
                System.out.println(guess[x]);
                won=false;
            }
            else
                for(int w=4; w<=5; w++){
                    if(guess[w].equals("lemons")){
                        won=false;
                        System.out.println("guess[w]");
                    }
                    else
                        won=true;
                }

        }
    }
    if(won=true){
        Balance=Balance+10;
        System.out.println("You have won!");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Try again!");
}


}
```

Comment: where is your game class?

Comment: Compilers are __very__ good at telling you why they won't compile something. There is a message somewhere. Please find it and post it here.

Comment: This isn't what's causing your program to not compile, but you should double check your bracketing. Specifically, the `else` statement in `equipmentNeeded()` [doesn't behave the way you think it does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020228/is-it-ok-if-i-omit-curly-braces-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment that there is probably an error message you're missing (Eclipse is pretty good about marking those up straight of the box). However, that's a completely different issue (although it is one you should put some effort into solving).

In `playGame()` you have the following line:

```
if(won=true){
```

The problem is you use a single `=`, meaning assignment. You want a double `==` which is a comparison. You cannot assign a value inside of an if condition. and that's what's causing your error.

```
x = 2;  //assigns the value of 2 to x.
x == 2; //compares the value 2 to x. The value of x does not change. Returns boolean.
```

Note that `==` compares references which is fine for most applications but for certian datatypes like strings you should se `string.equals()`.