# System.out.println doesn't print a line with no parameters?

Tags: java, parameters, println

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void mystery(int x, int y, boolean b, String s) {
        System.out.println(x*3 + "..." + x/y);
        if (b)
            System.out.println("yes");
        else
            System.out.println("no");
        for (int i = 2; i <= 5; i++)
            System.out.print(2*i);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println((double)(y/x));
        System.out.println(s.substring(3,7));
     } // end mystery

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         mystery(7,3,true,"freezing");
     }
}
```

I'm a little confused and I think I'm missing something. How come the output of the for loop in this code is 46810? Shouldn't there be a line in between each of the numbers?

Comment: If you mean the second `Sysout` after `for` loop, then you need to have braces with your loop.

Comment: Kind of a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8020228/ - you would do well to read this, especially Jon Skeet's answer.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to me that you wanted your loop to look like this:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= 5; i++)
 System.out.print(2*i);
 System.out.println();
```

But the `for` only applies to the first statement.  To include multiple statements in the loop, you need to enclose the loop body in curly braces:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
 System.out.print(2*i);
 System.out.println();
}
```

It's best to *always* use curly braces when writing a `for` loop, and also `while`, `do`, `if`, and `else`, even though the language allows you to have a body of just one statement without the curly braces.  For example:

```
 if (b) {
     System.out.println("yes");
 } else {
     System.out.println("no");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not with `System.out.print(2 * i);`. For the output you seem to expect change it to,

```
System.out.println(2 * i);
```

or add braces to your `for` loop like,

```
for (int i = 2; i <= 5; i++){
    System.out.print(2*i);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Java loops aren't controlled by indentation, you need braces to contain more than one line.

Comment: But there's a println() right after it. Wouldn't that skip a line?

Comment: @aaa Only if that `println` call was
 part of the loop.

Comment: @aaa Yes, it skips a line--_after the entire loop is done_.  Not in between every number.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= 5; i++)
{
    System.out.print(2*i);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println((double)(y/x));
    System.out.println(s.substring(3,7));
}
```

When you are using the `for` loop then it is recommended to put the code inside it in the curly braces `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop logic must be contained in `{}`