# Java: Is if , else if and else count as one statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, scope, curly-braces

Example:

```
if(Boolean){
    if(Boolean) something();
    else if(Boolean) something(); 
    else something();
           }
```

This is the same as

```
if(Boolean)
    if(Boolean) something();
    else if(Boolean) something(); 
    else something();
```

Is if, else if and else count as one statement?

Comment: No one should write such ugly, hard to read code.  Learn a better idiom.

Comment: [Is it ok if I omit curly braces in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020228/is-it-ok-if-i-omit-curly-braces-in-java) it is not.

Comment: This is totally not a duplicate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `if`/`else` pair is one statement. If you have `if`/`else if`/`else`, that's actually two if statements, with the second one being in the first one's `else` clause.

```
if(Boolean)                                                 \
    something(); <- one statement                           |
else                                                        | one
{                                                           | if
    if(Boolean)                              \              | statement
        something(); <- one statement        | one if       |
    else                                     | statement    |
        something(); <- one statement        /              |
}                                                           /
```