# How to find the index of an element in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to solve [this](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-092-introduction-to-programming-in-java-january-iap-2010/assignments/MIT6_092IAP10_assn03.pdf) question:

```
String[] names = {
"Elena", "Thomas", "Hamilton", "Suzie", "Phil", "Matt", "Alex",
"Emma", "John", "James", "Jane", "Emily", "Daniel", "Neda",
"Aaron", "Kate"
};

int[] times = {
341, 273, 278, 329, 445, 402, 388, 275, 243, 334, 412, 393, 299,
343, 317, 265
};
```

basically there are 2 arrays, one for the names and one for the times, array indexes are matching (for example Elena's time is 341), I have to find the fastest runner, so whoever has the smallest time is the fastest.

first I found the smallest value in times array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(times[i] < fastest)
        fastest = times[i];
}
```

but I don't know how to match names array with times array, I tried this but it didn't work

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(names).indexOf(fastest));
```

Comment: Why not just keep track of the index and use that when you loop?

Comment: use `HashMap` instead ?

Comment: tried putting `System.out.println(names[i]);` in for loop, in this case the last output would be the fastest but I just want only 1 output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
public class test {


public static void main(String[] args)
{

    String[] names = {
            "Elena", "Thomas", "Hamilton", "Suzie", "Phil", "Matt", "Alex",
            "Emma", "John", "James", "Jane", "Emily", "Daniel", "Neda",
            "Aaron", "Kate"
            };

            int[] times = {
            341, 273, 278, 329, 445, 402, 388, 275, 243, 334, 412, 393, 299,
            343, 317, 265
            };

            int fastest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int slowestRunnner = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
                if(times[i] < fastest)
                {
                    fastest = times[i];
                    slowestRunnner = i;
                }
            }

            System.out.println(names[slowestRunnner]);
}
}

System.out.println(names[slowestRunner]);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it worked, I did `int slowestRunnner` first, I didn't set it to zero and got an error, can you explain why I should set it to any integer in advance?

Comment: maybe i am just having a brain fart but the above code will always give you i = array.length -1 becuase you don't have brackets around the if statement therefore only fastest = times[i] will execute for the if and slowestRunner = i gets set every iteration of the loop...?

Comment: A local variable must be explicitly given a value before it is used, by either initialization or assignment, in a way that can be verified by the compiler using the rules for definite assignment.

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz you don't need braces with if in this condition because compiler will automatically include everything inside the if condition.

Comment: how does it know to include everything under the if? this isn't python so i wouldn't think the spaces identify them as being part of the if @nitinsh99

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz I would suggest you to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020228/is-it-ok-if-i-omit-curly-braces-in-java

Comment: it doesn't work, i just ran a simple example and it doesn't work, the no brackets only includes the first line after the if, every subsequent lines are not included and get called everytime inside the for loop, unless this is a java 8 only feature it won't work @nitinsh99

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz I can guarantee it works. See the screenshot.

Comment: No you're output is what i expected it's the last person in the array, that output is WRONG, the fastest person is John - 243 and NOT Kate who is the last person in the array and only has a time of 265 which would have been easy to see if you also print the fastest variable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130042/discussion-between-nitinsh99-and-raz-muh-taz).

Answer (score 1):

```
int minimum = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < times.length; i++){
    if(times[minimum] > times[i]){
        minimum = i;
    }
}
System.out.println(names[minimum]);
```

this should do the job

Answer (score 1):

Could you do:

```
var fastest = '';
var fastestIndex = '';

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(times[i] < fastest)
        fastest = times[i];
        fastestIndex = i;
}
```

Then use:

```
names[fastestIndex]
```

to get the name?

Answer (score 0):

call this way array_variable[index]

```
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
 if(times[i] < fastest){
    fastest = times[i];
    index = i;
 }
}
System.out.println(names[index]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way for this case:

```
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(times[i] < fastest) {
        fastest = times[i];
        index = i;
    }
}
System.out.println(names[index]);
```

But it will be better, if you use Map, that contains pair of name and number.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a field to track the index as :

```
int indexOfFastest = 0;
int fastest = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // this initialization makes sure first element is assigned to fastest within the iteration
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(times[i] < fastest) {
        fastest = times[i];
        indexOfFastest = i;
    }
}
```

and further modify your existing code as

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(names).get(indexOfFastest));
```

***Edit*** - Since the code with converting into a `List` ends up running the same evaluation as getting the values of array element at an index. Please prefer using

```
System.out.println(names[indexOfFastest]);
```

instead for better practices.

Comment: Rather `names[indexOfFastest]` than `Arrays.asList(names).get(indexOfFastest)`

Comment: @Dukeling sure. please throw some light on *why?*

Comment: I guess I could say something about writing more code which calls 2 methods and constructs a class, and ultimately just ends up running the same code as the former on top of that, but I guess it's more just a best-practices issue.

Comment: @Dukeling Okay :) I get that.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me

```
int fastest=0;
        for (int i = 1; i < times.length; i++) {
            if(times[i] < times[fastest])
                fastest = i;}
        System.out.println("Fastest runner is "+names[fastest]);
```