# Zero char on each string

Tags: java, string, concatenation

Why here i'm getting not concatenated string

```
String zero = "0";
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
            System.out.println(zero);
            zero += "0";
```

and here i'm able to concatenate?

```
String test = "Hello";
        System.out.println(test);
        test += "world!";
        System.out.println(test);
```

Comment: Hint: braces....

Comment: jeez, a hard day.

Comment: And this is why [you always use braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020228/is-it-ok-if-i-omit-curly-braces-in-java)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a for-loop has no curly braces then only the very next statement is repeated:

```
String zero = "0";
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
  System.out.println(zero);
  zero += "0";
}
```

Note that indentation has no syntactic value in Java, so the fact that both the println and concatenation statements are indented in your example misleads the reader to think that *both* statements are repeated when only the println statement is.