# What's the difference between increment index inside brackets and out of the brackets in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, increment

I am doing some exercises and I came across something, that I do not know much about. Below is a code and the part I Do not understand fully, I'll put in between stars, like `*this*`.

```
public int[] seriesUp(int n) {
  int[] result = new int[n * (n + 1) / 2];
  int i = 0;
  for (int j = 1; j <= n; ++j)
    for (int k = 1; k <= j; ++k)
      result[*i++*] = k;
  return result;
}
```

Can someone maybe explain what the difference between above and below is?

```
public int[] seriesUp(int n) {
  int[] result = new int[n * (n + 1) / 2];
  int i = 0;
  for (int j = 1; j <= n; ++j)
    for (int k = 1; k <= j; ++k)
      result[i] = k;
      *i++;*
  return result;
}
```

I changed the `i++` in the index brackets to `i` and incremented the `i` below, but this gives a whole other output, even though in my eyes it is the same.

Comment: You're missing braces.

Comment: The braces on the for loops that is.

Comment: You should **always** use braces with for loops. The result of not using braces is in this case the cause of the two snippets of code behaving very differently.

Comment: just indent the lines correctly, that is, the indentation of the new line should be less (spaces), same as the `return` - the `i++` command is outside both  `for`  loops  [as suggested always using braces is better]

Comment: The code you *intended* to write is equivalent, but there is a bug that is preventing it from giving you the expected results.  See the above comments.  This is one of the most common mistakes when modifying loop code: you meant to add a statement to the loop body, but you *actually* added it *outside* the loop.

Comment: The difference between increment index inside brackets and out of the brackets: one statement versus two statements!

Answer (score 4):

#### TL;DR

This

```
for (int j = 1; j <= n; ++j)
  for (int k = 1; k <= j; ++k)
    result[i++] = k;
```

is equivalent to below code (formatted with curly braces), which **increments** **`i`** **inside** the two for-loop:

```
for (int j = 1; j <= n; ++j) {
  for (int k = 1; k <= j; ++k) {
    result[i++] = k;
  }
}
```

And this

```
for (int j = 1; j <= n; ++j)
  for (int k = 1; k <= j; ++k)
    result[i] = k;
    i++;
```

is equivalent to this code (formatted with curly braces), which **increments** **`i`** **after** the two for-loop are executed:

```
for (int j = 1; j <= n; ++j) {
  for (int k = 1; k <= j; ++k) {
    result[i] = k;
  }
}
i++;
```

Basically, when curly braces are not used, instructions such as `for`, `while`, `if`, etc, interpret only the next line as the code block to be executed as part of its statement.

In your case you replaced `result[i++] = k;` (one line) for (two lines)

```
result[i] = k;
i++
```

leaving, this way, the second line (`i++`) out of the  statement to be executed by the for. Following the same principle, the outer loop ignores the `i++` sentence too.

When curly braces and code formatting are correctly used, this should never happen.

---

#### Long Story

This is the [`for`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-BasicForStatement) statement:

```
for ( [ForInit] ; [Expression] ; [ForUpdate] ) Statement
```

Where [`Statement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-Statement) can be (among others) an [`ExpressionStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-ExpressionStatement) or a `Block`.

The `ExpressionStatement` you used by doing `result[i++] = k;` was an [`Assignment`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-Assignment) (two of them, actually: `result[i] = k;` and `i = i + 1`, but, in **one** line), which is:

```
LeftHandSide AssignmentOperator Expression
result[i]    =                  k         ; // leaving out the `++` operation for simplicity here
```

Now, when you changed to the second alternative, without using curly braces, the `Statement` used by the `for` is still the first line next to it

```
result[i] = k; // <-- this keeps being the `Statement` taken by the `for`
i++            // and this line is not considered as a statement to be used by the for anymore
```

But, if you would have used curly braces, this would have become a [`Block`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-Block) statement in the form

```
{ [BlockStatements] }
```

Where [`BlockStatements`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-BlockStatements) is

```
BlockStatement {BlockStatement}
```

And  each [`BlockStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-BlockStatement) can be (among others) a [`Statement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-Statement). Thus you would have been able to put as many `Assignment`s (remember this is a `Statement`) as you wish to be executed by the `for`s statements.

---

*Further readings*:

- [Is it ok if I omit curly braces in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020228/is-it-ok-if-i-omit-curly-braces-in-java)