# Having issues calculating the average of the odd numbers of a list

Tags: java, file, average, filewriter

Our professor gave us a list of 982 numbers in a text file and we have read text from the file and print out some info about the numbers. I have everything correct so far, (she gave us the correct answers), except the total of the odd numbers. I can't figure out how to get the average of the odd numbers which is 48201.56.

I keep getting the result 97354, which is weird because I'm following the same method I used to find the average of all the numbers and the average of the even numbers.

```
        import java.io.*;
        import java.util.*;
        public class Homework1sem2
        {
           public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
           {
              System.out.println("Student name: Ethan Creveling "
              + "\nEmail: ec904066@wcupa.edu");
              double f = 0;
              double e = 0;
              double d = 0;
              int c = 0;
              int b = 0;
              int a = 0;
              File myFile = new File("numbers.txt");
              Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);
              while (inputFile.hasNext())
              {
                 int i = inputFile.nextInt();
                 a++;
                 d += i;

                 if(i%2 == 0)
                 {
                    b++;
                    e += i;
                 }
                 else
                    c++;
                    f += i;
              }
              System.out.println("Total number: " + a);
              System.out.println("Total even number: " + b);
              System.out.println("Total odd number: " + c);
              System.out.println("Total average: " + d/a);
              System.out.println("Total even average: " +e/b);
              System.out.println("Total odd average: " + f/c);


           }


        }
```

I would like to know why the answer for "Total odd average" isn't 48201.56. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it ok if I omit curly braces in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020228/is-it-ok-if-i-omit-curly-braces-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`f += i;` is being performed outside of the else statement which means that it is being called on every loop of the while. If you check your values, you should find that both f and d are the same value.

If you encapsulate your else statement as follows, this should fix the problem

```
else {
  c++;
  f += i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `else` statement is only performing the `c++;` operation.

Wrap it in brackets like this:

```
else {
  c++;
  f += i;
}
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the "total" (as `c`) is referencing the total occurrences of odd numbers, not the sum. The labeling is a bit confusing though. `f` is the sum of odd numbers. Therefore, `f/c` is the correct calculation for the average of odd numbers.

Comment: I removed my comments because I was, as @Tom, pointed out focusing on something minor. Sorry.